# Can you connect 2 separate flowcharts with one restricted area?

Tags: anylogic

Our model has a ProductionOrder seize some Operators. The seize block has a Prepare flowchart for the Operators to move through an airlock (PAL) into a room. After the ProductionOrder operation (a delay block), the Operators are released and have a Wrap-Up flowchart that sends them out of the room through the same airlock.  Because this airlock can only have 2 people, we need to restrict the combined Operators in the Prepare and Wrap-up flowcharts to 2 people in the airlock regardless of them coming in or going out (i.e. max 2 at any time).

[image]

If we do this by connecting the blocks with connectors, an error comes up basically saying you can't connect a Prepare flowchart to a Wrap-up flowchart.

[image]

Is there a way to link the circled queues and restricted area start blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a queue (PALqueue) use a wait block there (in both flows)

And you can do in the on enter of each wait block PALqueue:

```
if(PALCapacityLimit.entitiesInside()+PALCapacityLimit1.entitiesInside()<2){
    self.free(agent);
}
```

And in the on onter of the PalInLimit (both)

```
if(PALqueue.size()>0)
PALqueue.free(PALqueue.get(0)); //remember now PALqueue is a wait block
else if(PALqueue1.size()>0)
PALqueue1.free(PALqueue1.get(0));
```

And there you go :)

Comment: Thank you @Felipe. This technique is great!  I made a minor modification to the PALinLimit code by changing the second "if" line to "else if". Works like a champ!