# How to get around using Enter and Exit blocks in "Prepare" flowchart (Execution error "0 isn't supported for building resource behavior flowcharts")

Tags: anylogic

I have an airlock (small room called AL_2216) between 2 areas. The airlock has many different agent types passing through it (cart, product, operator, etc). There are queuing areas on either side of the airlock.

[image]

Because the space is small, I built a short flowchart that has a queue and restricted area blocks that all agents must pass through when going through this space. If the restricted area's capacity is full, the agents wait in either the InsideQueueArea or OutsideQueueArea depending on the direction they're going.

[image]

I send agents via Exit and Enter blocks to this flowchart and it works great on the top portion of the flowchart.

[image]

BUT if I try to use an Enter or Exit block in the prepare flowchart, I get this error:

[image]

I tried using a custom block instead of Enter and Exit blocks, but that creates a new instance of the code each time and the restrictions don't work together across the multiple custom blocks.

This airlock is just one of many in my model. Without referring to the same code, I'll have multiple copies that need to refer to each other's restricted areas and the flowcharts become huge and complicated. Is there a way to get around this?

EDIT:

I'm not sure what to do with these ports. They have no properties that do anything:

[image]
[image]

EDIT2:

Here's a file to see the behavior - [Model2.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4zzank5t35dmwa/Model2.zip?dl=0)
The Prepared flowchart portion is set to "ignore" so the code will run. You can see the operators and the carts passing through AL_2216 with only 2 being allowed at a time. If you uncheck "ignore" for the prepare flowchart, the error will trigger.

Comment: why didn't you use the same solution from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664864/can-you-connect-2-separate-flowcharts-with-one-restricted-area/58666784#58666784

what's the difference?

Comment: That was my original method, but maintaining the priority of who entered which wait block and when became very complicated when more than 2 flowcharts use the same airlock. This method uses a single FIFO queue.

Comment: You can keep all that information in a simple collection where you keep the queue... it should be easy... every time someone enters the wait block you add it to the collection... then you easily have a FIFO

Comment: Got the answer! Missed a setting to define the resource task start block. Thanks again, Felipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnyLogic sent the right answer!!

So I was asking Anylogic a different question and they recognized my name from this post! They sent a fix to me and it works exactly the way it should! The exception error message I was getting "out: 0 isn't supported for..." made me think the exit/enter blocks were not supported in perparation flowcharts.

But actually, the seizeCart block didn't know where to start the prep flowchart because it wasn't directly connected to the resource task start block. **A quick setting change under the Advanced section of the seizeCart block defining which resource task start block to start at did the trick!** Here's the email from AnyLogic:

[image]
*-The error text and documentation are not sufficient for understanding this (the error text is confusing), I suppose it is obsolete error text. We will rectify the description;*

*-Under the question there is a more generic discussion which seems to be unrelated to the initial problem. Please let me know if I miss something or if your model does not work as you expect even after adjustment of seizeCart block property.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the Enter and Exit blocks that lead to the bottom input of your seizeCart Seize block with simple `Port` objects (from the Agent palette).

As per the [help for Seize](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FSeize.html&resultof=%22%73%65%69%7A%65%22%20%22%73%65%69%7A%22%20):

[image]

So it wants a direct link to a `ResourceTaskStart` flow and your Enter/Exit combinations might be ... not "direct" enough... Try it.

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin but I'm not quite following. I replaced the Enter/Exit blocks with ports, but there aren't any properties of the ports that do anything. They make sense to me in a custom block, but I don't really know what they do here. See my EDIT above.

Comment: ok, maybe I didn't understand the question well enough. Let's try the other way around: Can you create a minimum-viable model that recreates the issue and explain from scratch again? I don't see why you need the Enter/Exit blocks in the first place...

Comment: Ok @Benjamin I’ll put a quick one together. The basic premise is that many flowcharts in my model will run through the enterAL_2216/exitAL_2216 flowchart as the agents navigate the network. This small flowchart will only allow 2 agents (carts, operators, pallet jacks, etc) into the AL_2216 node at any one time. Sometimes, the agents are resources moving through AL_2216 on their way to the agent that seized it.

Comment: I added a link to a file showing the behavior and why using the Enter/Exit blocks works so well for this application. [Model2.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4zzank5t35dmwa/Model2.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I have to agree with Benjamin....I think internally AnyLogic is checking the connection between RessourceTaskStart and the RessourcePort of your *seizeCart*, I unfortunately do not know for what reason they do that. I made the experience that AnyLogic cannot follow/analyse flowcharts that are connected by Enter/Exit modules. One example for this: AnyLogic automatically sets the Agent type flowing through for each element of a flowchart to the setting of the first element (Source/Enter), but it cannot do this with flows connected through Enter/Exit.

Comment: I think what this means for you is basically that for flowcharts of ressource preparation you cannot deploy the technique to modularise flowcharts with the use of Enter/Exit. Quite a pitty! To be sure of that I would check with the AnyLogic support, but I think the error message is quite clear on that.

Comment: The *port* trick of Benjamin might work, but probably the same problem arises as you have it now: AnyLogic doesnt consider it a single flowchart and complains in the case of the resource preparation flow. To try Benjamins suggestion, you would need to model the Airlock as an own Agent with one *in* port, a decision (SelectOutput5) and separate *out* ports for every possible area that you want to go to (instead of just a single function inside the Exit block as you have it now)

Comment: @Florian The airlock can be a separate agent (I coded it this way first and no error occurs) but I then end up with a new instance of passing through the airlock everywhere I insert the custom block into the flowchart (i.e. moveThruAL_2216_01, moveThruAL_2216_02, moveThruAL_2216_03, etc).  This doesn’t help because each instance then has restrictions that aren’t associated with each other (i.e. 2 of each agent passing through node AL_2216 but many more than 2 total agents). Is there a way to insert the same instance of a custom block agent into multiple places in a flowchart?

Comment: "Is there a way to insert the same instance of a custom block agent into multiple places in a flowchart?" --> nope. Can't you reroute your agents back through the one instance required, using ports?

Comment: Got the answer! Missed a setting to define the resource task start block. Thanks again, Benjamin and @Florian.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there are (not really documented) restrictions on what blocks you can use in preparation and wrap-up flowcharts, which mean what you're attempting won't work.

As you say, it's important to keep a single 'instance' of the airlock flow so that the restrictions (queue and restricted area) are 'global' **when this represents the same physical airlock**. (Otherwise a repeated custom block is precisely what you should use for each different physical airlock.)

Your best option (and assuming you needed to attach the Cart resource to the Product) is probably to

- Add dummy agents (via Source block `inject` calls) to a separate mini-process that represents your resource preparation requirement (but now not attached to the Seize block).
- Replace the Seize in your main process with a Seize-Wait-Release-Seize combination:

  - The Seize block seizes the cart as normal (*without* moving or attaching it; no 'Send seized resources' or 'Attach seized resources' options) and then injects an agent into your mini-process (which can use Exit and Enter blocks to use the airlock sub-process). This agent *represents* the seized resource agent (Cart) and thus should start where it starts and be animated so it looks like it. (You can make the actual Cart temporarily non-visible during this mini-process.)
  - When the agent reaches the end of the mini-process (at a Sink block), instantly move the related Cart to your node (use `jumpTo`), make it visible again and `free` the Product agent from the Wait block
  - Release the seized Cart and then immediately re-Seize it, but now attaching it (so the animation looks correct). If you use the Resource selection 'Nearest to the agent' option you should be guaranteed to seize the correct cart. (You can also use the 'Customise resource choice' option with some code to ensure that you absolutely always choose the same Cart.)

(It is simpler than the above if you don't care about having a correct animation, and you can use custom blocks to make this block combination reusable and thus not too clunky.)

**Edit**: A very similar alternative which also works (and is the basis for your own answer) is to have a dummy agent representing your Product in the sub-flow which seizes (and attaches) the actual Cart agent, leaving it at the Product's location to be immediately seized as above. This is slightly better since you don't have to worry about the visibility and 'jumping' of the real resource agent, plus you can move a Seize and a Release from the main flow (which now just has Wait-Seize) to the sub-flow (thus 'hiding them away').

Comment: I haven't double-checked, but I think it's *required* that you don't send the actual resource agent Cart through the mini-process since you otherwise have errors that an agent is in two flows at once (similarly to if you tried to send the Product through a separate flow whilst it was in a Wait block). In any case, the way here feels better conceptually to me anyway....

Comment: Funny you said that, I tried something similar on Wednesday and you get that exact error.

Comment: @KevinSwartz To be clear, I was saying that my answer avoids this problem by not sending the actual resource agent through the 'dummy' preparation flow (i.e., that aspect of it was specifically required). I can see your answer is a slight alternative to mine, switching one set of Seize-Release blocks from the main flow to the 'dummy' subflow, and having the sub-flow contain a dummy agent seizing the Cart, rather than a dummy agent *representing* the cart. Both ways work, but I think yours is slightly better---it avoids handling the movement and visibility of the real resource unit.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the above for completeness. (I also missed a step to 'jump' the real Cart resource once the dummy agent representing it had reached the product.)

Comment: Got the answer! Missed a setting to define the resource task start block. Thanks again, Stuart.

Comment: It actually wasn't a coincidence they recognised your name BTW! I'd contacted them to ask about what the apparent block restrictions are for prep/wrap-up branches, at which point they confirmed that the error msg is (very!) misleading and is actually due to the problem they responded to you about.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I ended up doing. It's the best I could come up with that could be easily replicated for lots of airlocks.

I've added a wait block (dummyThruAL_2216) to my Product flowchart prior to seizing the cart. This wait block injects a new Agent into sourceDummy at the cartHome node. The dummy then seizes a cart and moves through the airlock and it's restriction. Upon exiting the restriction, I check what type of agent and direct the agent to the correct exit block. The dummy agent and cart move to the Product where the dummy agent releases the cart and sinks. The sink frees the wait block and the Product seizes the cart that is right next to it and continues on it's journey.

[image]

It's an easy copy/paste to add more airlocks. Not as nice as my original, but what are you going to do... Thanks for everyone's help and suggestions.

Comment: Make sure your seizeCart01 block uses the Resource selection 'Nearest to the agent' option (or uses 'Customise resource choice' code to be explicitly sure) to ensure it seizes the correct Cart that just moved to you. (This issue is 'latent' if your Carts resource pool only has capacity 1, and would probably be 'accidentally OK' with a larger one, depending on your model, because the just-moved cart would remain the first-available one in the resource pool.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I got it to use the same cart. It works well, just annoying that I need to trigger the dummy. I'm trying to expand the routing a little more with this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312646/). Would appreciate your input.