# Is there a way to return a list of the nodes along a network between an agent and it's destination?

Tags: anylogic

I'd like to return and capture a list of the path elements and nodes that an agent will travel if given a moveTo() command. From this list, I can see if the agent will pass through certain nodes where the agent will behave differently (slow down, pause for 1 minute, etc.). I can then cycle through moveTo() commands for each node and change the parameters based on the node it's going through.

I'd love to give some sample code, but I'm not sure where to begin to get the list. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function to get the shortest route from source to target:

```
RouteData rd = RouteData findShortestPath(ILocation source, ILocation target, Node[] nodesToAvoid, Path[] pathsToAvoid);
```

You can access the elements of rd by calling `rd.getMovements().get(index).getNetworkElement()`. This will return an object which could be an instance of a path, or a node, or a rectangular node etc.

For more details you can look here: [AnyLogic Help - TransporterControl](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_Material%2Freference%2FTransporterControl.html)

Comment: Thank you Sarah. This is very similar to what I'm looking for, but unfortunately, I'm not using transporters, only agents and resources. I was hoping to find an agent submethod to moveTo() or distanceTo() or getNetwork(), but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Hi Kevin! I wasn't sure that this method would work for other agent types so I checked it with support and got this this answer: "This is a generic function, you can use it if you know the agents location (nodes). It does not matter are the agents transporters or not - just find where they are located, create the ILocation implementation (e.g. LocationNode) and pass the locations as arguments."
I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This worked well, Sarah. I ended up putting a dummy TransporterControl block in my model and used this code: `transporterControl.findShortestPath( new LocationNode( node ), new LocationNode( node1 ), null, null)
 .getMovements()`