# Can I use RouteData API for any agent?

Tags: routes, anylogic, routedata

[network with nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjX0I.png)
Let's say an agent is located at Node1 and the three resource units from one resource pool are located at Node2, 3, and 4 respectively.

When an agent is to seize one resource unit on nodes and moves to it, I used customize resource choice. An agent has to choose the closest one by the path distance, which is node 3 in this picture.

But the red node represent a bridge which will be broken at some point during simulation.

If the bridge is broken, the agent cannot move to node 3 and 4. Therefore it has to choose node 2.

In the question below,it says that the RouteData API can be used for the any type of agent, not only transporters.

[Is there a way to return a list of the nodes along a network between an agent and it's destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312646/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-the-nodes-along-a-network-between-an-agent-an)

So I was trying to use RouteData to get the list of nodes in route(agent->unit).

When the bridge is broken, I can change the node color to green then if the route contains any green node the agent does not choose that unit.

But I cannot find Anylogic Help page saying RouteData can be used for any type of agent.

What would be the best way to model my situation?

Comment: Not sure about the exact problem. Does it work with transporters? Then it would be the same for normal agents... Maybe revise & simplify the original question to get to the root problem you face? Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow